# How to change the quality of an animated gif via imagick in php

Tags: php, imagick, animated-gif

I want to change quality of animated gif image via imagick in php.
I wrote the below code :

```
$source = 'images/b.gif';
$imageDesc = 'images/finally.gif';
$thumb = new Imagick($source); 
$thumb = $thumb->coalesceImages(); 
foreach ($thumb as $frame) 
{ 
    $frame->thumbnailImage(300,300); 
} 

$thumb = $thumb->deconstructImages(); 
$thumb->setImageCompressionQuality(20);
$thumb->writeImages($imageDesc, true);
```

finally image (`$imageDesc`) was created but image's quality not be changed!

Comment: is it not working? how about the new image quality?

Comment: I use this command : `$thumb->setImageCompressionQuality($image_size -> image_size_quality);` but quality not set in `$imageDesc`

Comment: look@ http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagecompressionquality.php here the parameter of writeImages is the target dir. But your $imageDesc is not defined in the code above.

Comment: Gif is a 'lossless' format in the sense that the compression level does not change the output of the image. What are you hoping to achieve here?